# Interesting increment operator in C (in a while loop)

Tags: c

I want to implement the factorial algorithm, and the following code gives me wrong result for factorial(5)

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int i = 1, ret = 1;
    while(i++<=n)
        ret *= i;
    return ret;
}
```

Looks like the code will continue to run even when i = 6, I don't understand why the while loop didn't stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a post-increment operator which means the final check for `i <= n` happens before `i` is incremented for the final time. In other words, when `i` is 5 your code:

```
check if i <= 5 -> true

increment i -> i is now 6

execute loop -> executes for i = 6

check if i <= 5 -> false (i is now 6)
```

You should change to:

```
while(++i <= n)
```

Comment: "You are using a pre-increment operator", isn't `i++` the post-increment unary operator.

Comment: @kriegar - Yes. My brain decided it wanted to stop working. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do one thing per statement.

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int i = 1, ret = 1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        i++;
        ret *= i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Check the differences between the versions above and below this text.

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int i = 1, ret = 1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        ret *= i;
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i++` returns the value of `i` and only then increments `i`. (As opposed to `++i` which first incerements `i` and returns incremented value)

Answer (score 0):

That's how `i++` works. you need `++i`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing one extra iteration of the loop.

Instead of `(i++<=n)`, what you really want is making it `(i<=n)` and then add the `i++;` after the `ret*=1`.

This is actually much more cleanly done using a for-loop IMHO.